# Set value only when no null or zero otherwise throw exception

Tags: c#

I am looking for a shorthand how to say in one line:

```
int MyVariable = otherVariable (but if otherVariable is null or 0) then throw new Exception()
```

Comment: [`int MyVariable = otherVariable.GetValueOrDefault(0) == 0 ?  throw new Exception() : otherVariable.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw#the-throw-expression)?

Comment: @GSerg i get error: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'GetValueOrDefault' and no accessible extension method 'GetValueOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Then your `otherVariable` could not be null like you have suggested in the question. In which case  remove the `.GetValueOrDefault(0)` and the `.Value`.

Comment: @Arie The question indicated that `null` was a possible value.  `int` is not nullable.  `Nullable<int>` is though, which is what the first comment assumed you had.

Comment: @GSerg and can it be just like: otherVariable == 0 ? throw new Exception() : otherVariable

Comment: @GSerg i mean without .Value

Comment: That is that you get if you [remove `.GetValueOrDefault(0)` and `.Value`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60175147/set-value-only-when-no-null-or-zero-otherwise-throw-exception?noredirect=1#comment106433688_60175147)  from `otherVariable.GetValueOrDefault(0) == 0 ? throw new Exception() : otherVariable.Value`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Elvis" operator to make your integer nullable. For example you can use the "?" in some situations:

```
int? variable = null;
```

Or you can use it for methods:

```
int variable = SomeClass?.Method();
```

If your method returns a null value, the assignment won`t be applied.